# After 6 Serversocket event connection with same application futher ajax request is not getting sumitted

Tags: java, javascript, html, jakarta-ee

I am facing very strange problem when i am creating server socket event connection with java application deployed on tomcat .After making 6 server socket connection .it is not able to make new connection even when i am request simple url from ajax or from new tab it is not hitting application .I have checked through proxy tolls even request is not genearted from browser .if the same url i request from some other browser then request got submitted and response comes .

This means issue is at browser side not application side . I have checked with both mozila and google chrome but still no success .

Is there any kind of restriction with HTML 5 server socket Event .I am using following code

```
eventSource.addEventListener('trigger', function(event){
        var data=event.data;    
        var oFormB = document.getElementById('a'+tabId);
        var audioEnable;
        var sound;
        if(oFormB!=null&&data.charAt(data.length-1)=='b'){
            audioEnable=oFormB.elements.audibleAlarm[0].checked;
            if(audioEnable!=null&&audioEnable==true){
                sound = new Howl({  urls: ['js/sounds.mp3'],buffer:false}).play();

                //sound.stop();
                }else{
            //      alert(" Alarm Id:"+event.data+" Triggered.Tabs Id: "+tabId);
                }
            alert(" Alarm Id:"+event.data+" Triggered. Tabs Id: "+tabId);
            if(sound!=null){
                sound.stop();
            }
        }
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Maybe this explains this behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404464/increasing-google-chromes-max-connections-per-server-limit-to-more-then-6

Comment: Really Thanks .It is very much helpfull for me