# CEF : Change "max-connections-per-server" in CEF

Tags: chromium-embedded

Is it possible to change the "max-connections-per-server" (like Firefox) in CEF-Client.
Need it to show many mjpeg-streams in on tab.

In my case, the folowing is no solution.
[Increasing Google Chrome's max-connections-per-server limit to more than 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404464/increasing-google-chromes-max-connections-per-server-limit-to-more-then-6)

Answer (score 0):

The limit of 6 connections is currently hard-coded in Chrome:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/socket/client_socket_pool_manager.cc#47

However, with CEF, you can provide your own resource handler which could be limited as you please.

A custom resource handler is a subclass of [`CefResourceHandler`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefResourceHandler.html). It is plugged through a custom [`CefRequestHandler`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefRequestHandler.html) with an overridden [`GetResourceHandler`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefRequestHandler.html#GetResourceHandler(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser>,CefRefPtr<CefFrame>,CefRefPtr<CefRequest>)) method.

Similarly, a custom [`CefRequestHandler`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefRequestHandler.html) is plugged through method [`GetRequestHandler`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefClient.html#GetRequestHandler()) of your subclass of [`CefClient`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefClient.html).