# VideoJS - embedded videos not working after number 7

Tags: colorbox, video.js

I have a page with 10 videos. They are loaded in colorbox lightboxes.

I am using the standard videoJS markup.
Loading videos via: 
`<a href="#video1" class="inline">View</a></li>`

and:

`<div id="5ways" style="height: 348px">
    <video id="5ways" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
        preload="auto" width="618" height="348"
        data-setup="{}">
         <source src="//contiki-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/agent/training-tools/video/5ways_converted.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         <source src="//contiki-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/agent/training-tools/video/5ways_converted.WebM" type="video/webm">
         <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
    </video>
</div>`

The bottom-most 3 videos (where they are positioned in the HTML) won't load. Videos 8, 9, 10 just get the loading spinner.

There's nothing wrong with the markup/paths to the videos. I have tested the URLs and they work fine. I have also tested commenting out some of the other video tags, which causes the broken videos to start working.

EG. If I comment out video 1, video 8 starts working. 
Comment out video 2, video 9 starts working.
Comment out video 3, video 10 starts working.

The same is true for whatever order I do this in.

VideoJS will only allow 7 videos max to be embedded.

Anyone got any ideas? Or links to pages where more than 7 videos have successfully been embedded?

Comment: I have created a proof of concept here that, while different from what I was originally trying to do, suffers from the same issue:
http://jsbin.com/povuzolexi/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said over in the video.js issue tracker, it looks like you're hitting Chrome's max connections per domain. As well as not using `preload="auto"` you might try suggestions in this question, such as spreading the videos over different domains. You may be able to set up multiple cnames for your s3 bucket.

[Increasing Google Chrome's max-connections-per-server limit to more than 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8404464/740233)

Comment: The page I'm working on will eventually have something like 40 videos available, so the preload="none" option sounds like the way to go. 
Thanks for the help and suggestions.