# Javascript XMLHttpRequest: How many threads does it use?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

When you ask XMLHttpRequest to do an asynchronous work, how many concurrent work could run at the same time?

I am asking this because I use pooling, and my JavaScript is hanging when I open the forth connection. Aka I got 4 asynchronous objects of XMLHttpRequest and they all are doing extremely heavy networking task.

So is there such limitation for the concurrent requests that XMLHttpRequest can handle asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

The limit of how many parallel network requests are outstanding is browser-specific and sometimes configurable, but not from within the application. Ofc, you can always use less then allowed.

However, since javascript is single-threaded, unless you use web workers (which is somewhat a different story), then data processing will be serialized. Network requests are running in a parallel threads to the point of getting the data from the network.

Comment: Can you show me when it's configurable? Do you know how it works in Chrome?

Comment: Some times it is possible via browser configuration files or registry. Perhaps this will help: [previous SO on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404464/increasing-google-chromes-max-connections-per-server-limit-to-more-than-6)