# Increase the wildfly server concurrent thread processing

Tags: wildfly

I am using wildfly server. I have passed 14 requests to the server. The server processes my request 6 at a time. once the top 6 gets completed the next 6 request is processing. is there any other way to increase the count(6) of processing the request in wildfly so that all my request have to process at the same time.Processing 1st 6 requests [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6scV.png)

Once the 1st set of request got completed. next 6 requests started to process[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTcci.png)

Comment: It's not a WildFly limitation. It's Google Chrome that is restricting you to 6 concurrent connections to the same host.

Comment: Is there any other way to increase this limit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404464/increasing-google-chromes-max-connections-per-server-limit-to-more-than-6