# What is the reason why not all images are downloaded using .click ()?

Tags: javascript, dom

There is a script

```
let imgLink = document.querySelectorAll('.ssilkaimg');

for(let i = 0; i < imgLink.length; i++) {
  imgLink[i].click();
}
```

When I run the script, not all images are downloaded. 5 images can be downloaded, 10 can be downloaded, etc. But, mostly up to 15, but not all. Maybe there are some restrictions on downloading in the browser? Google did not find it.

Comment: Ruslan, in your example I can't any logic that might wait or verify images loaded status

Comment: This may only be a temporary solution but you could use a delay.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Yes, thanks, the postponement of the set timeout helped me. The images, as I understood, not all had time to download and the script tried to download them.

Comment: The for loop is synchronous, you may want to return this as a promise and loop differently.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK Yes, I figured it out after asking the question)) Thanks)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404464/increasing-google-chromes-max-connections-per-server-limit-to-more-than-6

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I can leave my answer, I will choose it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the problem is the loading of the images, being that the script starts directly without waiting for the loading to finish the images will not be downloaded all, using a delay bypass the problem. ([setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)).
However, I recommend adopting a more correct method by waiting for the page to load an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071314/javascript-execute-after-all-images-have-loaded)